# Jquery Date & Time on html/php page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date, arabic

I want to show the date (english & arabic) & time same as in following website :

http://bit.ly/2gHpUZ

because i'm not able to pick the code from this website but i need exactly the same to my html /php page ,

regards
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can get the code. Once the document has fully loaded the 'showTheTime' function is called in conjunction with the 'replaceText' function to translate the time to arabic:

```
function replaceText(node){
    if (node.nodeType == 3){
        node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace(/0/ig, '٠'); 
        node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace(/1/ig, '۱'); 
        node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace(/2/ig, '۲'); 
        node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace(/3/ig, '۳'); 
        node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace(/4/ig, '٤'); 
        node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace(/5/ig, '٥'); 
        node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace(/6/ig, '٦'); 
        node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace(/7/ig, '۷'); 
        node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace(/8/ig, '۸'); 
        node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace(/9/ig, '۹'); 
    }else if (node.nodeType == 1){
        $(node).contents().each(function (){
            replaceText(this);
        });
    }
}

function showTheTime(){
    now = new Date();
    now.setUTCHours(now.getUTCHours()+3);
    $('#clock').html(now.getUTCHours() + ":" + showZeroFilled(now.getUTCMinutes()) + ":" + showZeroFilled(now.getUTCSeconds()));
    setTimeout(showTheTime, 1000);
    replaceText(document.getElementById('clock'));
}

function showZeroFilled(inValue){
    if (inValue > 9){
    return "" + inValue;
}
    return "0" + inValue;
}


$(document).ready(function(){
    showTheTime();
});​
```

All you need to do is define or re-define the element 'clock' within your document.

Comment: i'm at beginner level , can you please help me with more details :

Comment: what code should i prove to my html page ?? some example please !!

Comment: Alex, I have created a jsfiddle to illustrate the dynamic clock: http://jsfiddle.net/LVc56/20/. With regards to the date, it is being generated server-side. This will point you in the right direction: http://www.ar-php.org/ar-example-Date-php-arabic.html

Comment: you are awsome dude :) i'll definitely try this :) thanks for your help

Comment: Do you have a link to the page?

Comment: no , can you please give me a favour & create me demo page (html or php) that shows just the date (arabic & english)as shown in demo link !!